# Is there a word that describes this feeling?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, mood

The rising star shows no remorse for the figment of existence to which man shows no resolve.
There is no depression, for there is no sadness.
There is no boredom, for there is no annoyance.
The world does not know, nor would the world give it consideration if it did know.
If mankind could hear the thoughts of thy brethren, it would not care to listen.
If mankind listened, there would be no thoughts to hear, for your indignation is not.
He who feels would rather study the cracks of time in the monuments of creation than enjoy thyself.
Ones mind is as clear as the sky which does not show.

I just wrote whichever words that came to mind about how I feel.
I'm not suicidal.

Comment: I feel like nothing. Not in the sense that I feel as if /I/ amount to nothing, but in the sense that I feel nothing. I don't /want/ to enjoy myself. Maybe it's a show of insistence, that I'm serious about how I feel, but I don't see how it would be. I just feel empty, devoid of emotion.

Comment: Although you say "there is no depression, for there is no sadness",  it is a mistake to think depression is sadness. Actual, (clinical) depression comes quite close to the overall vibe you describe: absence of feeling.

Comment: Is 'ennui' match what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Depression*: it's a lack of emotion, no desire, no feeling.

Also update thy verb conjugation, for ’tis the twenty-first century already.

Comment: As I was writing my comment, you answered :) +1 for depression, correctly used.

Comment: I suppose. Worthy of note is that it's entirely spontaneous—I only feel like this during certain periods, and after certain occurrences. I don't know where the way I spoke when writing the question came from, but I don't normally swrite like that.

Answer (score -2):

My guess for a word that matches is, "uncritical."